# Two Functions are calling in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

I am using `GoogleMaps` to show the location marker on screens after fetching the location from `Firestore` database but the problem is I have three functions.

First function is showing all the list of users on the google maps, I called it in `viewDidLoad()` method.

```
func showListOfAllUsers() {

for document in snapshot!.documents {
                print(document.data())
                let marker = GMSMarker()

                self.location.append(Location(trackingData: document.data()))

                print(self.location)

                 guard let latitude = document.data()["Latitude"] as? Double else { return }
                 guard let longitude = document.data()["longitude"] as? Double else { return }

                marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude as! CLLocationDegrees , longitude: longitude as! CLLocationDegrees)
                marker.map = self.mapView
                marker.userData = self.location
                marker.icon = UIImage(named: "marker")
                bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
                print("Data stored in marker \(marker.userData!)")
            }
 }
```

Now I presented a list of users in which I am passing the selected user co-ordinates to show the markers on the `GoogleMaps`.

```
func getAllLocationOfSelectedUserFromFirestore() {
for document in snapshot!.documents {
                print(document.data())
                let marker = GMSMarker()

                self.location.append(Location(trackingData: document.data()))

                print(self.location)

                 guard let latitude = document.data()["Latitude"] as? Double else { return }
                 guard let longitude = document.data()["longitude"] as? Double else { return }

                marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude as! CLLocationDegrees , longitude: longitude as! CLLocationDegrees)
                marker.map = self.mapView
                marker.userData = self.location
                bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
                print("Data stored in marker \(marker.userData!)")
            }
}
```

I used delegate method to pass the selected user information.

```
extension MapViewController: ShowTrackingSalesMenListVCDelegate {

func didSelectedFilters(_ sender: ShowTrackingSalesMenListViewController, with userID: String) {
    self.selectedUserID = userID
    self.userLogButton.isHidden = false
    print("The selected UserID is \(selectedUserID)")
    self.getAllLocationOfSelectedUserFromFirestore()  // called here the second function
}
```

Here is `GMSMapViewDelegate` function in which I am passing the user informations in **userData**.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    print("didTap marker")
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    self.mapView.endEditing(true)
    if let _ = self.activeMarker {
        self.infoWindowView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.activeMarker = nil
    }

    self.infoWindowView = MarkerInfoView()
    let point = mapView.projection.point(for: marker.position)
    self.infoWindowView.frame = CGRect(x: (point.x-(self.infoWindowView.width/2.0)), y: (point.y-(self.infoWindowView.height+25.0)), width: self.infoWindowView.width, height: self.infoWindowView.height)
    self.activeMarker = marker

    for mark in location {
        self.infoWindowView.storeNameLabel?.text = mark.name
    }
    print(self.infoWindowView.storeNameLabel?.text as Any)
    if let data = marker.userData as? [String:Any] {
        print(data)
        self.storeMapData = data
        print(self.storeMapData)

        var name = "N/A"
        if let obj = data["name"] as? String {
            name = obj
        }


    } else {

    }
    infoWindowView.delegate = self
    self.mapView.addSubview(self.infoWindowView)

    return true
}
```

It is showing the marker of the selected user on `GoogleMaps`. Now the problem is `GMSMapViewDelegate` function is same for both the above functions and it is showing the markers from both the functions on map. But I want to show only the selected user information on Maps. The red marker showing the selected user locations. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just put a boolean flag and when you select the user set it to true and check it in the delegate and clear map overlay and put your marker only